# Как разложить по переменным каждое слово из строки

Tags: python

Я могу вытягивать из JSON ответа бота словарь `['text']`, например я боту прислал строку `"255 01 12345 67890"`, вопрос в том, как из этой строки вытащить каждое значение, написанное через пробел и записать в переменные для JSON запроса уже для отправки в чужое API.

> Как из текста "255 03 12345 67890" вытащить и вписать:  '255' в
>   переменную 'mcc', '03' в переменную 'mnc', '12345' в переменную 'lac',
>   '67890' в переменную 'cid' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = "255 03 12345 67890"
parts = text.split()              # список [255, 03, 12345, 67890]

mcc, mnc, lac, cid = parts
```